# Why does higher voltage produce better torque from stepper motors?

Tags: voltage, motor, stepper-motor, efficiency, torque

I'm working with stepper motors and I have a question.

I have found that if I use a higher voltage switching source, I get better torques from the motor. Why is this?

Comment: Higher voltage > higher current > more power. BTW, some stepper drivers use that method, and provide a "current limiting" so the coils don't get damaged.

Answer (score 3):

It is common to see a small stepper motor being driven from 12V or 24V, but it only has 5Ω coil resistance and is rated for 1.5A.  Ohm's law tells us that 5*1.5 = 7.5V, so 7.5V should be the maximum input voltage limit.  So how does it not catch fire?!

The answer is that the driver is PWM-limiting the current. It turns the driving voltage on and monitors the current.  When the current exceeds 1.5A, it turns the voltage off and waits.  It repeats this thousands of times per second.  The net result is that the pulsed voltage *averages* to around 7.5V, and the current averages to 1.5A - within limits.

The *advantage* of using these higher voltages is the *rate* at which the current ramps.  Higher voltages cause the coils to charge faster, which in turn means two things:

1. More time for the selected pole to interact with the moving stator (more torque)
2. Higher usable top speed, because the coils physically charge faster.

This is especially important for steppers, as their torque rapidly dwindles at higher speeds.  If you need torque from steppers at high speeds, a higher-voltage source is needed.

There are limits though, and you may find that a different type of motor would be better-suited to such an application (like a servo motor.)

Comment: Just a note to clarify - not a toy "servo motor" like would be found in the steering of a model car - an [actual servo motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomotor).

Comment: Great answer. But how does the driver "know" the motor specs and its limits? It might be able determine the resistance, but it still needs the V or A limits to get the 3rd...

Comment: Usually there is a current limit on the driver.  Larger drivers usually have dip switches to set the current.  Even the venerable [A4988 stepper driver](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=A4988+stepper+driver+module) has a potentiometer to limit the current.  So adjust it lower for smaller motors, and higher for larger motors.

Answer (score 2):

Steppers require current limits to prevent overheating, but a higher supply voltage means it can reach that actively-controlled current limit faster if such controls are included by design.

Primitive drivers just drive more power out from more power in with passive current limiting by the coil resistance. I=V/R

Torque is a function of current.

Comment: is torque a function or current or power? I would think a 10w motor would have more torque than a 1w motor, even if they both used 2A...

Comment: Yes @dandavis  but for a fixed motor T is a function of I.

Answer (score 1):

The higher the rotation speed is, the shorter is the time for each coil to ramp up the current. Current increase is direct proportional to the available voltage and current porvides the torque.

With a higher voltage you also extend the maximum rotation speed with useful torque. However at low rotation speeds with plenty of time per step, the current increase must be limited. Typically this is implemented with high frequency PWM.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I had an idea that it worked like an RL circuit but I wasn't sure. ;)